# program to read i/p from a txt file as a condition for if/else in batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement, batch-processing

I am making a script that first runs a command on a server and stores the response from server to a file (`>>output.txt`). Next, the script will read the `Output.txt` file and see if `x=0` and use it as a condition to if/else.

For example, my script will check server replication status & will update output.txt file with below line:

```
x=0 (if replication complete)

x=any number (if there is some data yet to get replicated)
```

(We don't know the number of line where the value to x will be stored in output.txt as the script will keep updating the file & we need to read the last line always)

Now, I want my script to read the output.txt file and if x=0, it should shutdown the server, else not. How should I write my script?

Answer (score 1):

to read the very last line of a textfile, use a `for /f`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (outfile.txt) do set LastLine=%%a
echo %LastLine%
```

If you need the last line, that starts with `x=` (and there could be other lines too), modify to:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type outfile.txt^|findstr /bi "x="') do set LastXLine=%%a
echo %LastXLine%
```

If you are interested in the value only:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type outfile.txt^|findstr /bi "x="') do set LastXValue=%%a
echo %LastXValue%
```